# Firefox skew blurring issue

Tags: css, firefox, transform, skew

I am using the following transform code to skew an element that I am absolutely positioning after my header tag. The codepen shows the complete code...

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBxxYg)

```
-webkit-transform: skewX(35deg);
transform: skewX(35deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
transform-origin: 100% 0%;
```

It looks great in Chrome but when viewed in Firefox, the bottom edge of the after element has a blur to it, causing it to look a little strange.

[Here's an example image for comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ4Hc.jpg)

Does anyone know of a way to correct the issue in Firefox? I had found some answers online stating you need to add a transparent border or other border recommendations, but not of those seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Looks perfectly fine for me in Firefox 51.

Comment: Looks right for me in Firefox 50 as well.